# Find object in a generic list by Index

Tags: c#, list

This is my generic list. I would like to return the object CompanyEmail by finding the object based on the index. How do I do this ?

```
 List<CompanyEmail> companyEmail = (List<CompanyEmail>)ViewState["companyEmail"];
```

Comment: The naming of your objects and collections is confusing.  Your collection is called `companyEmail` and your collection is also a collection of `CompanyEmail` objects.  What are you trying to return?  Are you looking to return a specific `CompanyEmail` object from your `companyEmail` collection, based on a given index?  Or are you trying to get a specific index given a specific `CompanyEmail` object?

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
 List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
 Data temp = data[1];
```

in your list:

```
companyEmail[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

why on index, you may use the Dictionary Class (it's generic too). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

hope I got you right.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx

Use:

```
List<T>.FindIndex(Predicate)
```